# Import screenshot images automatically, using an Automator script and Folder Action, referenced photos on server

Tags: photos, automator, permission

I have my Apple Photos.app library on my iMac and my referenced photos on a networked Mac mini. The goal is to import all screenshot images automatically, using an Automator script and Folder Action, to a local Photos.app library with the images referenced and residing on the Mac mini server.

I have created a Folder Action on the iMac that checks for changes on the mounted volume at:

`smb://192.168.5.1/Godzilla/Screenshots_master`

The Folder Action runs when I take a screenshot and the screenshot is saved to the `Screenshots_master` folder on the remote volume.

Initially the Automator Script's import action ran but failed with this notice in Photos.app

[image]

I fiddled around with permissions on the Mac mini server which stopped the "Cannot Import Item" from appearing, however the image is still not imported into the Photos.app library. This leads me to think it may be a permissions issue.

To work on that I moved to the Mac mini and added ACLs to `/Screenshots_master`

```
sudo chmod +ai "group:everyone group:staff allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit" /Volumes/Godzilla/Screenshots_master
```

that resolved the message but the image was still not imported

```
chmod -N
chmod +ai "group:everyone allow file_inherit,directory_inherit" /Volumes/Godzilla/Screenshots_master
```

The image is still not imported and there is no message.

Setting up the Automator script and Folder Action on the Mac mini doesn't work because it wants to use a local Photos.app library and in my case the library is on the iMac.

Permissions on `/Volumes/Godzilla/Screenshots_master`

```
john@Mac-mini ~ % ls -lae  /Volumes/Godzilla/Screenshots_master 

total 16
drwxrwxrwx+  3 john  staff   102 Oct 15 17:06 .
 0: group:everyone inherited allow file_inherit,directory_inherit
drwx---rwx  41 john  staff  1462 Oct 15 16:09 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 john  staff  6148 Oct 15 16:41 .DS_Store
 0: group:staff inherited allow read,write,execute,append,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
 1: group:everyone inherited allow read,write,execute,append,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
```

Comment: Are you able to view the screenshots that are saved to the Godzilla server?

Comment: @ErniePC12 yes, they are moved to the folder, Photos.app just won't let them import.

Comment: Can you connect to the server and import them into Photos manually?

Comment: @ErniePC12 yes, that is not what I am trying to accomplish. I am trying to get this automated.

Comment: I understand. We are trying to determine if this is an issue with the file or the automator script. manually run the automator script and check the results of each step to determine if the correct information is being passed.